# if i convert a file's contents into a single large number and express it as a mathematical expression, does it mean I have compressed the file?

Tags: algorithm, math, compression

assuming the mathematical expression has less number of characters than the original number.
example-

20880467999847912034355032910578 can be expressed as (23^23 +10)

this looks like a good compression method. Will it work for compressing large files?

UPDATE- i didn't mean converting a file into a large binary number. lets say i have a text file and i replace all the characters in it with their ascii values. now i have a large number in the decimal number system. i can express it as a mathematical expression like in the example above.

Comment: Obviously not: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle.

Comment: oli charlesworth, i have asked more than one question. which question are you answering with 'no' ?

Comment: "Will it work for all numbers"

Comment: How big the number is doesn't matter to the compression ratio...rather how big the file was. And it's somewhat unlikely you would find such a convenient expression. I would say you then have compressed the file, but wouldn't bet on it being able to be uncompressed in a reasonable time.

Comment: so will it work for most numbers?

Comment: I can't find a link for it, but this reminds me of something I once read years ago.  With precise enough instruments (that being the part which makes this impossible), any amount of data can be compressed into a single mark on a small scale.  For example, suppose you have a 1-inch bar.  If you express the binary data as a single (very large) number, then just place a decimal in front of that number.  Make the mark *exactly* that decimal's distance from one end of the bar to another, and you've represented all of that data in a single mark.  Of course, it would need *very* precise equipment.

Comment: its ok if such calculations take a long time. i just want to know whether it will work or not.

Comment: @David, a 1985 story by [Murakami Haruki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murakami_Haruki) uses the idea of an [encyclopedia on a toothpick](http://everything2.com/title/Encyclopedia+on+a+toothpick) but I think the idea is rather older than that

Comment: You only need to ask yourself if, when you have a file compressed with your method, you could again compress it, and so forth. Obviously, there will be a point where another compression will not work. If this were not so, it would be hard times for disk manufacturers. Because, why should I buy a terabyte disk if I could represent huge amounts of data in a few bytes?

Answer (score 5):

If you take the contents of a file as a large binary number, and find an expression which evaluates to that number *and can be stored more compactly than the number itself*, then yes, you have compressed the file.

Unfortunately, for most files, you'll never find such an expression.

Simple logic (see the link posted by @OliCharlesworth) should convince you that it's impossible to find such an expression for all or even most files. Even for files which might have a suitable expression, finding it will be *very, very* difficult. If you want to convince yourself of this, try this challenge:

Take the following ASCII string:

"Holy Kolmogorov complexity, Batman! Compress this sucker down good and you'll get a pretty penny, my fine lad!"

Interpreted as a binary number, with the high-order digits coming first, that is: 2280899635869589768629811602006623364651019118009864206881173103187172975244099647369151382436996220022807793898568915685059542016541775658916080587423284053601554008368389985872997499032440860090224967472423163775276043175694884234152335588829534778866153948275745.

Try to find a polynomial which evaluates to that number. All the numbers used must be integral, and the total number of decimal digits appearing in the polynomial must be less than 80. If you succeed, I will send you a small cash prize by PayPal.

Comment: What do you mean by a polynomial with 8 terms or less?  f(x) = that_number is a polynomial with 1 term which always evaluates to that number.

Comment: My intention was that the number of digits in the polynomial would be significantly less than the original number. Sorry for not defining the challenge properly. I have adjusted the definition to set a clear target for the compression ratio which should be attained.

Answer (score 5):

The notion you're looking for is Kolmogorov complexity - it's a measure of how algorithmically incompressible a number is.  See [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmically_random_sequence) for a [rigorous definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmically_random_sequence#Three_equivalent_definitions) and [examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmically_random_sequence#Properties_and_examples_of_Martin-L.C3.B6f_random_sequences) of such numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by definition.  You have correctly defined compression as representing something larger with something smaller.

How do you propose to do this?  How often will that work?  There's the rub.