# How can I compress a very large number(big number obtained by replacing characters in a text file by its ascii values)?

Tags: algorithm, math, compression

i'm not talking about  specific language, just in general. i am trying to find out ways to compress a text file by replacing each character by its ascii value so that the resultant is a big number. since a big number can be expressed mathematically in fewer characters, file can be compressed.

Comment: Does this differ from your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482380/if-i-convert-a-files-contents-into-a-single-large-number-and-express-it-as-a-ma) where it was explained this can't work?

Comment: yes. This time, I am asking the community for suggestions how we can achieve something close to that, some way that can work in at least SOME situations.

Comment: You characters _are_ stored as a number. It's a stream of bits. Going for the numerical representation makes it bigger rather then smaller, making your goal _even more complex_ to achieve.

Comment: @SumitSingh Then it's best if you state that difference in your question. Otherwise, we'll think it's just the same question repeated again.

Comment: "a big number can be expressed mathematically in fewer characters". Not generally, no. You can devise an encoding scheme which makes some big numbers representable in a fewer number of bytes, but the cost is always making other numbers harder (longer) to represent. Your losses will always equal or exceed your gains, due to what is called the pigeonhole principle.

Answer (score 3):

Well, yes, a big number can be expressed mathematically, and potentially save some space doing so. So if you convert each character to its ASCII value, then every character is expanded from a single byte to 1, 2, or 3 bytes. That is, 'A' becomes '65'. 'z' becomes '122'. For most text, figure the expansion ratio at something like 2.5 to 1.

So take a 1,000 byte text file. Convert all the characters to their corresponding ASCII values. You now have a 2,500 digit number. There are some cases in which that number could be expressed in fewer than 1,000 characters. But those are special cases. In general, you're not going to compress data by first converting it to a form that's 2.5 times the size of the original.

But if you want to try, it's simple enough.

```
Open input file as binary
Open output file as text

for each byte in input
    cast the byte to an int and output its string representation
```

In C, that last statement looks like:

```
printf("%d", (int)c);
```

Assuming that `c` is the byte that you read from the input file.

You now have a file in which all the characters are 0-9. For example:

```
Hello, world
```

Becomes

```
72,101,108,108,111,44,32,119,111,114,108,100,
```

Except that the commas won't be there:

```
721011081081114432119111114108100
```

You're welcome to try your hand at coming up with a compression scheme using your technique. I think you'll find that it works on a very small subset of possible inputs, and when it does work it takes a very long time to find an appropriate mathematical formula. It'd be easy enough to test by downloading the full text of Wikipedia and trying to compress individual articles. When you think you have something that works well, I'd certainly be interested in testing it.

Answer (score 1):

First, we state some assumptions:

1. You want to have a "lossless" compression, that is, you want to be able to restore the file after compression. (otherwise, we can just "represent" each file with the single bit 1)
2. The text in the file is assumed to be ASCII, which is just a sequence of one-byte characters (it doesn't matter actually what encoding we use, but to simplify things up)
3. Any of the possible characters are equally likely to be present in the text (i.e., the universe we're talking in is all possible file)
4. Each one-byte character can take value from 0-255 (known to be extended ASCII)

**First setting answer: There is no advantage in converting text to number since it's already a number**

Using these assumptions, **any file is actually a big number already**, more specifically, big binary number. If the file has length `n` characters, it is a binary number with `8*n` bits. So there is no advantage of "converting it to a large number", since it's actually already a number.

I hope you are clear on this concept.

Now we go on to what is actually possible with "converting text to number to compress it"

**Second setting answer: There is 12.5% space-saving, assuming only the first 128 characters are present in the file**

Your claim that "since a big number can be expressed mathematically in fewer characters" might seem to be true if you are looking at a small subset of text, namely, when we use only the first 128 characters of ASCII (i.e., violates assumption 4), which is the more commonly used set of characters. In that case, we can actually just represent each character as 7-bit binary number instead of 8-bit. By doing so we already save 12.5% space.

Now, the more interesting one.

**Third setting answer: There is this thing called Huffman Compression**

[Huffman Compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) saves space by representing each character in fewer bits, by harnessing the natural distribution of characters. In natural files, some characters appear more times than others (i.e., violating assumption 3), and if we use shorter bit-sequence to represent those characters, in the expense of expressing other less often characters using more bits, we can actually save space. The best performance of Huffman Compression on ASCII would be 87.5%, achieved when the file contains only a single character repeated many times.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a range coder. It can use a fraction of bits.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good answers here, but I'd like to add a couple of things.
*justhalf* has the best points I think:

Let's see how we can 'convert' text into a number:

1) You have a set of ASCII bytes, say. For each one, you write a number between 0 and 255.
How much space does each of those integers take? - Exactly the same space as the ASCII:
Which is no coincidence, ASCII is just a set of rules for interpreting what the numbers 0-255 mean
in the first place.

2) You swap each character for a number, then chain them, then store the number. This seems good, maybe
if you had a rule that swaps 'a' with '1': 'aaaaaa' would map to 111111, which can be stored in one byte!
But what about 'k'='11' and 'aa'=11'? (This appears to break Jim Mischel's response?)

However, there is a more serious problem here: You are storing a string of length n in a set of bytes with 
256^n possible values. This is **tight**: you might need all of those representations at some point.

You now create a one-to-one mapping from those values to numbers. There will still be exactly the same
number of possible numbers: 256^n (each of the n characters has 2^8 possibilities). And the smallest way to
represent 256^n possibilities is using log_2(256^n) bits. Which is 8n. This should be familiar. It's the same as having n bytes of length 8 just as we had before!

The problem you have is that, without any knowledge of the **distribution** (how likely each letter is to
appear) of your input letters, you could be in the case that every character is equally likely.
Thus, there is nothing gained by encoding some strings with smaller representations than others.

However, as others mentioned, if you DO know the distribution function of your input. Say your text is 
a string of DNA, and you only have four letters: 'G,T,A,C'. You only need two bits for each letter, and you can compress your input by four times!

For more reading, take a gander at the Wiki on [Information Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory).